# html data is not rendering property in html using python django

Tags: python, html, django

i could not display the html data sent from python in the html page.

when i open the html in view source mode, it thing data is rendered as messed

### html code

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>servername</th>
<th>cpu</th>
<th>memory</th>
<th>cdrivespace</th>
<th>ddrivespace</th>
<th>fdrivespace</th>
<th>gdrivespace</th>
<th>pdrivespace</th>
<th>kdrivespace</th>
{{ data }}
</table>
```

### python view

```
    data = callFileReaderMain( form.cleaned_data['session_key'] )

    return render(request,'marketplace_output.html',{'data' : data })
```

### view source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>marketplace output server details</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>servername</th>
<th>cpu</th>
<th>memory</th>
<th>cdrivespace</th>
<th>ddrivespace</th>
<th>fdrivespace</th>
<th>gdrivespace</th>
<th>pdrivespace</th>
<th>kdrivespace</th>
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;W01GCTIAPP01A&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;3.0&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;93.0&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;42.0&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;40.0&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;0&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;0&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;0&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;0&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: see the pic of the final page]

Answer (score 3):

In your html template, add a `safe` tag:

```
{{ data|safe }}
```

Comment: But make sure you trust the source of `data` because by marking it safe, you're also opening up the possibility of script injections.

Comment: Sure noted let me try and let u know